# Parallel matrix multiplication in rust

Tags: rust, multiprocessing

I want to parallelize matrix multiplication in Rust. I've written a sequential algorithm (`mul` function) and a parallel one (`mul_par`).

The `mul_parallel` is supposed to work in almost the same way as the sequential version, but it divides the work into a number of chunks equal to the number of CPUs found by `num_cpus::get()`.

Each chunk is spawned in a separate thread. Here's my code:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct RsMatrix {
    data: Arc<Vec<Vec<f64>>>,
    rows: usize,
    cols: usize,
}


impl RsMatrix {
    /// Creates a new matrix from a 2D array of floats.
    fn new(data: Vec<Vec<f64>>) -> Result<Self, String> {
        // check if all rows have the same length
        let row_len = data[0].len();
        if !data.iter().all(|row| row.len() == row_len) {
            return Err(String::from("All rows must have the same length"));
        }
        let rows = data.len();
        let cols = row_len;
        Ok(Self { data: Arc::new(data), rows, cols })
    }

    /// Multiplies matrices.
    fn mul(&self, other: &Self) -> Result<Self, String> {
        if self.cols != other.rows {
            return Err(format!(
                "Invalid matrix dimensions. \
                The number of columns of the first matrix should be equal to the number of rows \
                of the second matrix. Got {} and {} instead.",
                self.cols, other.rows,
            ));
        }

        let mut result = vec![vec![0.0; other.cols]; self.rows];

        for row_a in 0..self.rows {
            for col_b in 0..other.cols {
                for i in 0..self.cols {
                    result[row_a][col_b] += self.data[row_a][i] * other.data[i][col_b];
                }
            }
        }

        Ok(Self::new(result)?)
    }

    fn mul_par(&self, other: &Self) -> Result<Self, String> {
        if self.cols != other.rows {
                return Err(format!(
                    "Invalid matrix dimensions. \
                    The number of columns of the first matrix should be equal to the number of rows \
                    of the second matrix. Got {} and {} instead.",
                self.cols, other.rows,
            ));
        }

        use num_cpus;
        let num_threads = num_cpus::get();
        let result = Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![vec![0.0; other.cols]; self.rows]));
        let chunk_size: usize = (self.rows as f32 / num_threads as f32).ceil() as usize;
        let mut handles = Vec::with_capacity(num_threads);

        for th in 0..num_threads {
            let start = th * chunk_size;
            if start >= self.rows {
                break;
            };
            let result = Arc::clone(&result);
            let self_data = Arc::clone(&self.data);
            let other_data = Arc::clone(&other.data);

            let is_last_thread = th == num_threads - 1;
            let end = if is_last_thread {
                self.rows
            } else {
                (th + 1) * chunk_size
            };

            let other_cols = other.cols;
            let self_cols = self.cols;

            let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
                for row_a in start..end {
                    for col_b in 0..other_cols {
                        let mut sum = 0.0;
                        for i in 0..self_cols {
                            sum += self_data[row_a][i] * other_data[i][col_b];
                        }
                        result.lock().unwrap()[row_a][col_b] = sum;
                    }
                }
            });
            handles.push(handle);
        }

        for handle in handles {
            handle.join().unwrap();
        }

        let result = Arc::try_unwrap(result).unwrap().into_inner().unwrap();
        Ok(Self::new(result)?)
    }
```

The problem with my code is that when I run a simple benchmark that I've prepared (multiplying 100x100 matrices), the parallel version is much slower. What could be a reason for that?

```
Running 100 tests of 1000x100 * 100x100 matrix multiplication
Starting benchmark
Rust implementation total: 2.9226980209350586s
Rust implementation per iteration: 0.029226980209350585s
Rust implementation (parallel) total: 8.718234777450562s
Rust implementation (parallel) per iteration: 0.08718234777450562s
```

---

My benchmarks are rather simple and they look somewhat like this:

```rust
// matrix code skipped

use rand;
use rand::Rng;


const ROW_COUNT_A: usize = 100;
const COL_COUNT_A: usize = 100;
const ROW_COUNT_B: usize = 100;
const COL_COUNT_B: usize = 100;
const NUM_TESTS: usize = 1000;


fn generate_test_matrices() -> Vec<(RsMatrix, RsMatrix)> {
    let mut result = Vec::with_capacity(NUM_TESTS);
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    for _ in 0..NUM_TESTS {
        let matrix_a = (0..ROW_COUNT_A)
            .map(|_| {
                (0..COL_COUNT_A)
                    .map(|_| rng.gen())
                    .collect::<Vec<f64>>()
            })
            .collect::<Vec<Vec<f64>>>();
        let matrix_a = RsMatrix::new(matrix_a).unwrap();
        let matrix_b = (0..ROW_COUNT_B)
            .map(|_| {
                (0..COL_COUNT_B)
                    .map(|_| rng.gen())
                    .collect::<Vec<f64>>()
            })
            .collect::<Vec<Vec<f64>>>();
        let matrix_b = RsMatrix::new(matrix_b).unwrap();
        result.push((matrix_a, matrix_b));
    }

    result
}

fn test_matrix_mul(test_data: &Vec<(RsMatrix, RsMatrix)>) {
    for (matrix_a, matrix_b) in test_data {
        let _ = matrix_a.mul(&matrix_b).unwrap();
    }
}

fn test_matrix_mul_parallel(test_data: &Vec<(RsMatrix, RsMatrix)>) {
    for (matrix_a, matrix_b) in test_data {
        let _ = matrix_a.mul_par(&matrix_b).unwrap();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let test_data = generate_test_matrices();
    // check time execution of sequential multiplication
    let start = std::time::Instant::now();
    test_matrix_mul(&test_data);
    let duration = start.elapsed();
    println!("Time elapsed in sequential multiplication is: {:?}", duration);

    // check time execution of parallel multiplication
    let start = std::time::Instant::now();
    test_matrix_mul_parallel(&test_data);
    let duration = start.elapsed();
    println!("Time elapsed in parallel multiplication is: {:?}", duration);
}
```

The output I get from that is:

```
Time elapsed in sequential multiplication is: 2.71852745s
Time elapsed in parallel multiplication is: 8.5174711s
```

Comment: `result.lock` is the problem. It pretty much negates the entire parallelism by re-introducing a choke point.

Comment: If you claim performance numbers, please **always** also include your benchmark code. There's no point in arguing about performance if we can't even reproduce it.

Comment: @Finomnis thank you for your answer, I edited the the question to contain the tests. They are not exactly the same I used initially, because I am playing with PyO3 and my tests were written in Python. The version I added now in Rust does basically the same thing and the parallel version also appears to be slower.

Is there another way of doing it without a mutex so I can avoid locking?

Comment: I'm working on a more comprehensive answer, be patient ;)

Comment: Your test output states `Running 100 tests of 1000x100 * 100x100 matrix multiplication` and yet you are multiplying `100*100` matrices in the other test ... Which one is it?

Answer (score 3):

The mutex `lock` is the main problem, because it is a single threaded choke point for all the parallel threads.

Further, since the introduction of [`std::thread::scope`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.scope.html), the usage of `Arc` in this example is  no longer required and might further (even if only a little bit) increase your performance.

The `lock` however, is by far the biggest problem. If we don't use `Arc` here, our possibilities become a lot more.

There's two ways to implement it without `lock` that I can think of right now:

- splitting the output into parallel slices, with [`split_at_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut)
- by using [`rayon`](https://crates.io/crates/rayon) and, more specifically, its parallel iterators

Here's code for all of those, including code for the `Mutex` based variant without `Arc`:

- `lib.rs`

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;
use std::{sync::Mutex, thread};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct RsMatrix {
    data: Vec<Vec<f64>>,
    rows: usize,
    cols: usize,
}

impl RsMatrix {
    /// Creates a new matrix from a 2D array of floats.
    pub fn new(data: Vec<Vec<f64>>) -> Result<Self, String> {
        // check if all rows have the same length
        let row_len = data[0].len();
        if !data.iter().all(|row| row.len() == row_len) {
            return Err(String::from("All rows must have the same length"));
        }
        let rows = data.len();
        let cols = row_len;
        Ok(Self { data, rows, cols })
    }

    /// Multiplies matrices.
    pub fn mul(&self, other: &Self) -> Result<Self, String> {
        if self.cols != other.rows {
            return Err(format!(
                "Invalid matrix dimensions. \
                The number of columns of the first matrix should be equal to the number of rows \
                of the second matrix. Got {} and {} instead.",
                self.cols, other.rows,
            ));
        }

        let mut result = vec![vec![0.0; other.cols]; self.rows];

        for row_a in 0..self.rows {
            for col_b in 0..other.cols {
                for i in 0..self.cols {
                    result[row_a][col_b] += self.data[row_a][i] * other.data[i][col_b];
                }
            }
        }

        Ok(Self::new(result)?)
    }

    pub fn mul_par_mutex(&self, other: &Self) -> Result<Self, String> {
        if self.cols != other.rows {
            return Err(format!(
                    "Invalid matrix dimensions. \
                    The number of columns of the first matrix should be equal to the number of rows \
                    of the second matrix. Got {} and {} instead.",
                self.cols, other.rows,
            ));
        }

        let num_threads = num_cpus::get();
        let result = Mutex::new(vec![vec![0.0; other.cols]; self.rows]);
        let chunk_size: usize = (self.rows as f32 / num_threads as f32).ceil() as usize;

        thread::scope(|s| {
            for th in 0..num_threads {
                let start = th * chunk_size;
                if start >= self.rows {
                    break;
                };
                let result = &result;
                let self_data = &self.data;
                let other_data = &other.data;

                let is_last_thread = th == num_threads - 1;
                let end = if is_last_thread {
                    self.rows
                } else {
                    (th + 1) * chunk_size
                };

                let other_cols = other.cols;
                let self_cols = self.cols;

                s.spawn(move || {
                    for row_a in start..end {
                        for col_b in 0..other_cols {
                            let mut sum = 0.0;
                            for i in 0..self_cols {
                                sum += self_data[row_a][i] * other_data[i][col_b];
                            }
                            result.lock().unwrap()[row_a][col_b] = sum;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        let result = result.into_inner().unwrap();
        Ok(Self::new(result)?)
    }

    pub fn mul_par_split_at_mut(&self, other: &Self) -> Result<Self, String> {
        if self.cols != other.rows {
            return Err(format!(
                    "Invalid matrix dimensions. \
                    The number of columns of the first matrix should be equal to the number of rows \
                    of the second matrix. Got {} and {} instead.",
                self.cols, other.rows,
            ));
        }

        let num_threads = num_cpus::get();
        let mut result = vec![vec![0.0; other.cols]; self.rows];
        let chunk_size: usize = (self.rows as f32 / num_threads as f32).ceil() as usize;

        thread::scope(|s| {
            let mut offset = 0;
            let mut leftover_result = result.as_mut_slice();

            for _ in 0..num_threads {
                let split_pos = chunk_size.min(leftover_result.len());
                let result;
                (result, leftover_result) = leftover_result.split_at_mut(split_pos);

                let start = offset;
                offset += result.len();

                let self_data = &self.data;
                let other_data = &other.data;

                let end = start + result.len();

                let other_cols = other.cols;
                let self_cols = self.cols;

                s.spawn(move || {
                    for row_a in start..end {
                        for col_b in 0..other_cols {
                            let mut sum = 0.0;
                            for i in 0..self_cols {
                                sum += self_data[row_a][i] * other_data[i][col_b];
                            }
                            result[row_a - start][col_b] = sum;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        Ok(Self::new(result)?)
    }

    pub fn mul_par_rayon(&self, other: &Self) -> Result<Self, String> {
        if self.cols != other.rows {
            return Err(format!(
                    "Invalid matrix dimensions. \
                    The number of columns of the first matrix should be equal to the number of rows \
                    of the second matrix. Got {} and {} instead.",
                self.cols, other.rows,
            ));
        }

        let mut result = vec![vec![0.0; other.cols]; self.rows];

        result.par_iter_mut().enumerate().for_each(|(row_a, data)| {
            for col_b in 0..other.cols {
                for i in 0..self.cols {
                    data[col_b] += self.data[row_a][i] * other.data[i][col_b];
                }
            }
        });

        Ok(Self::new(result)?)
    }
}
```

- `bench/matmul.rs`

```rust
use std::hint::black_box;

use criterion::{criterion_group, criterion_main, Criterion};
use rand::prelude::*;

use rust_playground::RsMatrix;

pub fn create_random_matrix(x: usize, y: usize) -> RsMatrix {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let data: Vec<Vec<f64>> = (0..y)
        .map(|_| {
            let mut row = vec![0.0; x];
            rng.fill(row.as_mut_slice());
            row
        })
        .collect();

    RsMatrix::new(data).unwrap()
}

macro_rules! do_bench {
    ($c:expr, $name:ident, $m1:expr, $m2:expr) => {{
        let correct = $m1.mul(&$m2).unwrap();
        assert_eq!(correct, $m1.$name(&$m2).unwrap());
        $c.bench_function(stringify!($name), |b| {
            b.iter(|| black_box($m1.$name(&$m2).unwrap()))
        });
    }};
}

pub fn criterion_benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
    let matrix1 = black_box(create_random_matrix(100, 100));
    let matrix2: RsMatrix = black_box(create_random_matrix(100, 100));

    do_bench!(c, mul, matrix1, matrix2);
    do_bench!(c, mul_par_mutex, matrix1, matrix2);
    do_bench!(c, mul_par_split_at_mut, matrix1, matrix2);
    do_bench!(c, mul_par_rayon, matrix1, matrix2);
}

criterion_group!(benches, criterion_benchmark);
criterion_main!(benches);
```

```
mul                     time:   [3.4327 ms 3.4607 ms 3.4960 ms]
mul_par_mutex           time:   [3.2972 ms 3.3377 ms 3.3880 ms]
mul_par_split_at_mut    time:   [3.1037 ms 3.1472 ms 3.2026 ms]
mul_par_rayon           time:   [1.6733 ms 1.6939 ms 1.7222 ms]
```

What's the takeaway?

- There isn't much to gain from parallelism in matrix-matrix-multiplication. Things like cache effects and memory throughput are most likely a higher contributor. Also, for larger matrices the [strassen algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) becomes a lot faster. Always optimize algorithmically before parallelizing.
- If you parallelize, don't do it manually. Use an automatic load-balancing framework like `rayon`.

I hope you learned something :)